Mean difference (continious data) (in meta analysis) (Within-group unstandardized or standardized mean differences)
I am working on a meta-analysis project and I am completely new to this topic, so any advice would be highly appreciated. Specifically, if you could provide a reference or code in R, that would be very helpful.
In this project, which includes the results of around 9 publications, the question is whether the treatment leads to an improvement in disease symptoms (pain) or not. All the publications used paired t-tests or Wilcoxon signed-rank tests to compare the groups (before and after treatment). The included publications usually have different numbers of participants (before treatment and after treatment) due to missed visits and study withdrawals. We have access to the values of mean, standard deviation (SD), number of participants (N), and p-values.
The structure of our data is (Random example)
Study    Before_mean   Before_Sd   Before_n   After_mean  After_Sd   After_n
Study1      5.1           8           22          4.1       3.1         21
Study2      6.1           4.1         32           6.4      3.4         30
 

I am looking for some practical advice (with some code in R if possible) to show me how meta-analysis could be used correctly on this type of study, especially when we do not have access to the value of correlations.
Also, if the included publications used different scales (one publication uses 1-10 to measure pain, another uses 1-100), but I tried to adjust the reported values to the same scale, do I still need to calculate the standardized mean difference (or just calculate MD would be enough)?

It is hard to answer this without knowing what your scientific question is. Do you want to know whether the change is different in the two studies (which is not a meta-analysis question). Do you want to test whether there is any change at all? Incidentally doing random effects with two studies is very optimistic.

The Cochrane Handbook explains how to, and some of the concerns, about calculating the Change Score (https://training.cochrane.org/handbook/current/chapter-06#section-6-5-2-8).

@
mdewey,
Thank you so much for your time. The question is whether the treatment leads to an improvement in disease symptoms (pain). All the publications used paired t-tests or Wilcoxon signed-rank tests to compare the groups (before and after treatment).

@ mdewey, We collected around 9 publications and are planning to conduct a meta-analysis. We only have access to the mean, standard deviation (SD), and p-values. I have reviewed many references but could not find a suitable one to show how to work with this type of data. We have pre- and post-treatment scores (mean, SD). I am looking for a reference or practical guideline (or code in R) to show how to apply meta-analysis to this study.

@abousetta, thank you so much for the comment. I went through Cochrane but I need a reference to provide a practical example (or any code and function in R). For example, in our study, the included publications usually have different numbers of participants due to missed visits and study withdrawals. Additionally, some of the publications applied nonparametric tests, so we cannot calculate the t-statistic from the p-value, etc.

@abousetta, I just edited the question for more clarification.
